# node.js body-parser bad interpretation of Content-Type:x-www-form-urlencoded and Form-data JSON

Tags: node.js, body-parser

I have a client request with

```
Content-type: Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

And Form-Data like this (json):

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"print","params":{"id":"lp0","doc":"<section>
<p>&nbsp;sitedemo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><br><barcode>                   CLODGCGMM                    
</barcode><br><br><hr><drawer></drawer><br></section>"},"id":1501151330950}
```

The node.js server use body-parser middleware like this :

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

A console.log(request.body) give me something like this:

```
{ '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"print","params":{"id":"lp0","doc":"<section>
<p>': '',
'nbsp;': '',
'nbsp;sitedemo': '',
'nbsp;':'',
'&nbsp;</p><br><barcode>':''
'.......}'}
```

A json object is built having keys made by lines and values null .

How can i retrieve the exact object send by client (i have no access to client)

Thank you.

Comment: "i have no access to client" — The client is broken. You shouldn't pander to their errors. Insist they fix the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The client is broken when it's stating in the headers that the request body is URL-encoded but it's sending JSON.

If that's really the situation, you need to prevent those requests from being decoded by `body-parser`, and do the decoding manually.

Instead of this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Try this:

```
app.use(
  bodyParser.raw({ type : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
  function(req, res, next) {
    try {
      req.body = JSON.parse(req.body)
    } catch(e) {
      req.body = require('qs').parse(req.body.toString());
    }
    next();
  }
);
```